# what is invalid url 'apt://arc-theme/'given, exiting

Tags: 17.10

When i clicked on install arch package then shows this...

[image]

Comment: You have to contact the maintainer of the them it appears it is either no longer maintained or, more likely with the change to wayland, not yet available for 17.10

Comment: @Panther opening a link in my browser works, and i get the dialog for installing software via apt-url.

Comment: @Videonauth - Same package as in the question ?

Comment: apt://arc-theme, yes same link. just have put it into my firefox url field and it works.

Comment: The package itself is in the 'universe', maybe OP hasn't enabled this repository.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're using a browser which is well integrated. That is, installed via package manager.

Secondly, make sure your system has `apturl` package. If it doesn't, install it with this command

```
sudo apt install apturl
```

That that, the link should work and prompt you with installation of the package.